# What is the use of "this.toString()" in get()?

Tags: kotlin, tostring, getter-setter, getter

I found this piece of code in the [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html):

```
var stringRepresentation: String
get() = this.toString()
set(value) {
    setDataFromString(value) // parses the string and assigns values to other properties
}
```

I don't understand what `this.toString()` does here. `this` refers to the whole object. Why would we want it converted to a string, every time the object is accessed? Should it actually be `field.toString()`? (but that would be redundant too)

Comment: Where in the Kotlin docs is it?

Comment: Probably because set doesn't do something to set value to the field, so the field is empty. It should be intended for the object's toString() call since, `foo.stringRepresentation` looks more like we want string representation of foo object.

Comment: @mattfreake I have updated the question with the link. The code in question is under the section "Getters and Setters".

Comment: Thanks, the docs at the link match what Tenfour04 says below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is probably from an imaginary class that can serialize itself into a String by copying its property values to JSON or some other serialized String format. If these properties are mutable, you would want it to generate a new String each time you get the value. And since it has a setter, this imaginary class's `setDataFromString` function probably takes JSON or some kind of String representation and deserializes it to its own properties.

The getter is only called when `stringRepresentation` is accessed.

The setter is not using a backing field, so there's no reason for the getter to use the backing field value.